# Parsing a nested XML with python

Tags: python, xml-parsing

I have searched and tried the python library for XML data such as xml.etree.ElementTree and have looked for a similar solution from StackOverflow and other websites. However, I haven't found yet the solution for my case.

The XML file that I have as shown below:

```
<xmlInfo>
  <NodeName Dn="Santiago_server"/>
  <DataInfo>  
    <Period duration="60" end="2020-11-19 18:00:00"/>
    <measT X="1">CPU</measT>
    <measT X="2">Memory</measT>
    <measT X="3">Disk</measT>
    <measV object="Server#1">
        <P X="1">7</r>
        <P X="2">3</r>
        <P X="3">8</r>
    </measV>
    <measV object="Server#2">
        <P X="1">10</r>
        <P X="2">12</r>
        <P X="3">11</r>
    </measV>
  </DataInfo>
</xmlInfo>
```

The expected result from the above XML file as shown below:

```
Date         Time        CPU-Server#1   CPU-Server#2    Memory-Server#1   Memory-Server#2   Disk-Server#1   Disk-Server#2             
2020-11-19   18:00:00         7            10               3                   12               8                11
```

Your feedback is really appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: What exactly are you struggling with? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Looks like you should [parse the XML](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.parse) into a tree, and then perhaps [find the elements](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree.find) that you need, in your case `measV/P` elements. Learn a bit about [XPath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) when you work with XML.

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with your XML format. I have made a little modification. I don't know if it can meet your needs.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc, utils, req

xml = '''
<xmlInfo>
  <NodeName Dn="Santiago_server"/>
  <DataInfo>  
    <Period duration="60" end="2020-11-19 18:00:00"/>
    <measT X="1">CPU</measT>
    <measT X="2">Memory</measT>
    <measT X="3">Disk</measT>
    <measV object="Server#1">
        <P X="1">7</P>
        <P X="2">3</P>
        <P X="3">8</P>
    </measV>
    <measV object="Server#2">
        <P X="1">10</P>
        <P X="2">12</P>
        <P X="3">11</P>
    </measV>
  </DataInfo>
</xmlInfo>
'''

doc = SimplifiedDoc(xml)
rows = [['Date','Time', 'CPU-Server#1', 'CPU-Server#2', ' Memory-Server#1', 'Memory-Server#2', 'Disk-Server#1', 'Disk-Server#2']]
for dataInfo in doc.selects('DataInfo'):
    row = []
    period = dataInfo.select('Period>end()').split(' ') # Get date and time
    row.extend(period)
    # measT = dataInfo.selects('measT>text()')
    measVs = dataInfo.selects('measV').selects('P>text()') # Get all P

    for i in range(len(measVs[0])):
        for measV in measVs:
            row.append(measV[i])
    rows.append(row)
print (rows)
```